# Setting calibration for openni Kinect - running into max value

Tags: calibration, kinect, openni, dynamic-reconfigure, openni-launch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to calibrate my Kinect so that the RGB and depth data overlap.  I am running openni_launch and using dynamic_reconfigure_gui to tweak the values.

I have a good value for depth_ir_offset_x (-1.8) but the maximum value for depth_ir_offset_y (10) is insufficient.  It looks like depth_ir_offset_y=20 would be ideal, although I am limited to 10.

Any ideas on how to break this limit?
Also, should I submit this as a bug?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/30907/setting-calibration-for-openni-kinect---running-into-max-value/) by [bkx](https://answers.ros.org/users/1731/bkx/) on ROS Answers with karma: 145 on 2012-03-30

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Resolved by editing and recompiling openni_camera.

---

Originally posted by [bkx](https://answers.ros.org/users/1731/bkx/) with karma: 145 on 2012-04-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0